# DO i have to apply activation function on Max value in Max pooling?

Tags: opencv, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, convolution, subsampling

I am trying to implement convolutional neural network by Lecun. I have two questions. 
1) Do i have to multiply activation function on the  (max_value * weight_value) in the maxpooling layer. 
2) if yes than in backpropagating the error as i selected only one value from 2x2 receptive field. How can i distribute the error for the other 3 values in the receptive field. Should i replicate one error for all 2x2 window. 
3) If no than in backpropagation How can i take determinant of the output i.e. (x*(1-x)? As to find gradient, we need derivative of the activated weighted sum i.e f'(x)
4) USing stochastic diagonal livenberg marquardt method, What should i take the value for eeta, and meeo in equation (21) page 2319 of Lecun Paper http://enpub.fulton.asu.edu/cseml/summer08/papers/cnn-appendix.pdf

I will be thankful for any explanation, or code sample etc. 
Regards

Comment: @lizusek with due respect do you have any idea of it?

Comment: @Roger Rowland Sir, can you give me some information related to this? Regards